# Get all children from a given parent in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I would like to retrieve all children from a given parent (and optionally their level depth). Also, if possible, I would like to get it in a single query or store procedure.

Something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441821/getting-all-parent-rows-in-one-sql-query) by Mark Byers, only in reverse direction.

My table structure is like this:

```
id      parent
1       0
2       1
3       0
4       1
5       2
6       5
7       2
8       4
```

so i f want the children for 1 I'll get:

```
+2
 ++5
  +++6
 ++7
+4
 ++8
```

if want the children for 2 I'll get:

```
 ++5
  +++6
 ++7
```

and if want the children for 4 I'll get:

```
+8
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:** nested set model is no good to me

Comment: Where r u getting 1,4 from? I mean which col ur referring to..

Comment: @SOaddict That's the id col

Comment: Try with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391660/retrieve-hierarchy-from-a-table-like-this/16392049#16392049

Comment: @Meherzad The thing is that nested set is no good to me

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to ditch this adjacency model and change your structure to a nested set. Nested sets are great for fast selecting and removes the need for any recursive structures. However it does come with a price, inserts, updates and deletes are more painful. I did write a [blog](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2006/12/sql-nested-sets.html) post on this a while ago and it is MsSql based but it will port to MySql easily. Google also [throws up](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&site=webhp&sa=X&ei=Gw1hT-zQGZK7hAfak5HYBw&ved=0CB0QvwUoAQ&q=nested%20sets%20versus%20adjacency%20model&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=18235671e0456e0f&biw=1600&bih=799&ix=seb&ion=1) some good posts.

Another suggestion is to load all the rows from the database and then write a recursive method in your front end code and cache the output. I use this approach if I only have a couple of hundred rows in my table.

Comment: In my opinion, nested sets are a poor workaround that is only needed if the DBMS in use doesn't support recursive queries.

Comment: Depends on lots of factors, if you are really concerned with performance as you have a large recordset, then IMO nested sets wins hands down. Is it most definitely NOT a poor workaround.

Comment: Also this makes an interesting read, http://jsimonbi.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/sql-hierarchy-comparative-performance-2/ but remember you choose the model that sits right with you.

Answer (score -3):

Following Query will give you all the child tables for a table in MySQL.

Give database name and table name as parameter

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
       REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = "database"
AND    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = "table";
```