# SQL : Get child of of an element

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table of following structure.

```
**Table elements :**

element_id  element_name    parent_id
1           UIG             0
2           CAM             1
3           IHG             1
4           USR             1
5           DBL             1
6           APD             1
7           RTM             1
8           OCR             2
9           IRT             3
10          ICR             3
11          OCR             2
12          USH             1
13          AML             1
```

I need to find child elements of a given element.

I made the following query :

```
SELECT parent_id,GROUP_CONCAT(element_id)
FROM elements
WHERE parent_id='1'
GROUP BY parent_id
```

which returns,

```
+-----------+--------------------------+
| parent_id | GROUP_CONCAT(element_id) |
+-----------+--------------------------+
|         1 | 2,3,4,5,6,7,12,13        | 
+-----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

While I need also need the childs of element 2 and 3, which should result into

```
+-----------+------------------------------------+
| parent_id | GROUP_CONCAT(element_id)           |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
|         1 | 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13        | 
+-----------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I achieve this without procedures and just a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `in` operator on a subquery.

```
select group_concat(element_id)
from chpr
where parent_id in (
  select group_concat(element_id)
from chpr
where parent_id = 1
group by parent_id)
;
```

---

** AS per OP's comment the levels are definitely a concern**

However based on the initial sample data and request, here is the [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/701f6/3) that provides the results as per the question's expected output.

The only change is that one needs to group by both `element_id` and `parent_id` the innner most first subquery.

Not a very elegant query at all:

```
select 1 as parent_id, group_concat(x.element_id)
from (
(select element_id
from chpr
where parent_id in
(select element_id
from chpr
where parent_id = 1
group by element_id, parent_id
))
union all
(select element_id
from chpr
where parent_id = 1
group by element_id, parent_id
)) x
;
```

Results:

```
PARENT_ID   GROUP_CONCAT(X.ELEMENT_ID)
1           8,9,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,13
```

Comment: I guess it will not work where the level of child is more then two.

Comment: I think you need to expand your question to include all the not obvious bits and the assumptions you've made about our understanding.

Comment: Sorry I was away. Check out this extremely ugly code in [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11f22/1) I have a very slow connection at the moment so unable to update the answer somehow. @Ciarán I too got the initial impression that OP just needs the extra parent_ids.

Comment: @user1263746 can you take a look at this demo and comment please?

Comment: Sorry, it fails after second level. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: What is your second level? Are you planning to search *zig zag* till when? ;) In the question at initial level didn't see you mentionining multiple levels. You are better off witha procedure of a function in this case.

Comment: Stored procedure it is then... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IN ()` predicate...

```
SELECT '1' As Parent_Id,GROUP_CONCAT(element_id)
  FROM elements 
 WHERE Parent_Id IN ('1','2','3')
 GROUP BY '1';
```

Some database require the `GROUP BY` in this scenario others don't but it's fairly good practice to include it even if it is not needed.

Incidentally, I suspect Parent_Id is a numeric of some sort in which case it should really read...

```
SELECT 1 As Parent_Id,GROUP_CONCAT(element_id)
  FROM elements 
 WHERE Parent_Id IN (1,2,3)
 GROUP BY 1;
```

You could actually exclude the `1 As Parent_Id` and `GROUP BY 1` completely.

If you can only specify one value use a sub-query...

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(element_id)
  FROM Elements 
 WHERE Parent_Id IN (SELECT Element_Id
                        FROM Elements
                       WHERE Parent_Id = 1)
```

Comment: Ah. It might have been useful to include that fact in your question. In which case you will need a sub-query. I have amended my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah well, I guess that was obvious. Sorry for that... :)

Comment: I'm afraid it wasn't obvious at all, but never mind these things happen. :-)

Comment: So what's the possible solution? I am sorry for the goof up.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my this question

[Finding all parents in mysql table with single query (Recursive Query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query)

And here is the source for this kind of work.

http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to read the parents. It's the childs of a specific set of parents that's the required result set.

Comment: well reversing the process in explain extended link can do anything thats why i posted the link of explainextended