# Finding all parents in mysql table with single query on some condition

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

Next SQL is working:

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.name 
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := IDParent FROM objects WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 10) vars,
        objects m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN objects T2
ON T1._id = T2.ID
```

but I can only find ID by doing query:

```
SELECT ID FROM objects WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%prod%')
```

Tell me how to combine these queries

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query?rq=1

Comment: table structure and sample data plsssssss

Comment: TABLE objects(  
    ID INT(11),  
    name VARCHAR(50),  
    IDParent INT(11)  
    )