# Return category having relevant keyword along with its super-categories

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help provide a way forward with this one. I hope I can explain it well enough.

A simplified version of my category/subcategory database schema looks like this:

**tblAllCategories**

```
record_id  title                    level   parent_cat_id   parent_id   keywords
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Antiques & Collectables  0       NULL              NULL          junk
2          Art                      0       NULL              NULL          
25         Furniture                1       1                 1             
59         Office Furniture         2       1                 25            retro,shabby chic
101        Chairs                   3       1                 59
```

Notes:

- Level 0 = top-level category, level 1 = second level, etc
- parent_cat_id is the top-level category (i.e. having level 0)
- parent_id refers to the level immediately above the relevant level

I added the keyword column to assist keyword searches so that items in certain relevant categories would be returned if the user entered a keyword but did not select a category to drill down into.

So, at the front end, after the user enters keyword, e.g., "Retro", I need to return not only the category that has the term "retro" in its keyword column, but also all higher level categories. So, according to the schema above, a search on "retro" would return category 59 along with its super-categories - 25 and 1.

The query should be sorted by level, such that the front end search results would look something like this (after necessary coding):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query

Comment: That switches off id rather than keyword and mine already has level column. Difficult for me to apply. Trying though.