# How to store cascade categories in DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, categories

I have a problem about storing multiple categorical data. One category can have any size of cascade depth. I think it is not good idea to create more tables with relationships. What is the best way of storing this kind of categorical data.

```
ex categories:
 -MainCategory1
     -subcategory1
            -subcategory11
            -subcategory12
            -subcategory13
                   --subcategory131
     -subcategory2
            -subcategory21
            -subcategory22
                   -subcategory221
            -subcategory23
                   -subcategory231
                        -subcategory2311
 -MainCategory2
     -subcategory21
            -subcategory211
                   -subcategory2131
                        -subcategory2131
            -subcategory212
            -subcategory213
                   -subcategory2131
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define parent child structure

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES (ID INT, PARENT_ID INT, NAME VARCHAR)
```

then you select categories that have no `PARENT_ID`

```
SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL
```

they are masters and then on each layer you select

```
SELECT C.* FROM CATEGORIES C 
INNER JOIN CATEGORIES C1 ON C1.PARENT_ID = C.ID
```

to get children of current record.

And then insert into categories

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORIES 
SELECT 1, NULL, 'MainCategory1'
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 1, 'subcategory1'
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 10, 'subcategory11'
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 10, 'subcategory12'
UNION ALL SELECT 13, 10, 'subcategory13'
UNION ALL SELECT 131, 13, 'subcategory131'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'subcategory2'
-- ...AND SO ON
```

Comment: I got this idea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

One common practice would be to create a single table where each category has an id, a name and a parent id (with top categories having parent id of `null`):

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
     id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
     name VARCHAR(100),
     parent_id NUMERIC FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES categories(Id)
)
```

Some of your data, e.g., would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO categories VALUES (1, 'MainCategory1', null);
INSERT INTO categories VALUES (2, 'subcategory1', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server implements the `hierarchyid` data type.

You should consider using that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-standing issue with using a relational database to contain hierarchical data. Generally it was done using self-referencing tables but that has always been an absolute bear to work with. I always find it somewhat fitting that the designer of Java noticed that the best hierarchical database in common use was the directory structure of the disks. So that's what Java uses!

Many DBMSs have enhancements to make working with hierarchical data easier. They work (or not) with varying degrees of success and difficulty for the developer. One method I recently worked out as a response to a question here at SO can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284995/adapt-query-to-return-category-heirarchy-by-keyword/24377125#24377125). It's not complete. But actions such as moving a node or entire subtree from one place to another would just be a mathematical operation, not readjusting FK pointers.