# database with Category, (Optional subcategory) and sub-subcategory (service)

Tags: android, database-design, android-room

Thought I can handle it all by myself, but... I thik I've wasted too much time... 
Hello everyone! I'm struggling with Room database structure - I'm not sure if wheter my approach is correct or not. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to add Services (sub-subcategories) to Categories, but there may be optional Subcategories as well:

Category -> Service

Category -> optional Subcategory -> Service

What I've already did (skipped some basic parts of code):

a) created entities

```
@Entity
class Category
int id
String name

@Entity
class Subcategory
int id
String name
int categoryID

@Entity
class Subcategory
int id
String name
int categoryID
int subcategoryID
```

b) created join table

```
@Entity
class Join
int id
int categoryID
int subcategoryID
int serviceID
```

It's straight-forward when a category has subcategory with any services:

```
id | categoryId | SubcategoryId| ServiceId|
-------------------------------------------
1  |          1 |            1 |        1 |
1  |          1 |            1 |        2 |
```

but in case there's no subcategory and service belongs to category only:

```
id | categoryId | SubcategoryId| ServiceId|
-------------------------------------------
1  |          1 |         null |        1 |
```

I put `null` as SubcategoryId and check if subcategory is null

So the question is: **is this approach correct in terms of relational database design ?**

Or should I:
1. create category-subcategory, subcategory-service, category-service join tables and conncet them somehow eventually in one, big join ?
2. or add categoryId and subcategoryId to the service ?

Any comments, tips & tricks much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than *joining* it into other relational tables, i would use following approach:

Let's say you have only two categories, one is primary *(Main category)* & second is secondary category *(Sub category)*.

I would create entity for **`Category`** in single table like this:

```
@Entity
class Category
int id // It's our primary key here
String name
int parentId // To detect if category is Main/Sub. How? "Null" if Main, "main category" id if child
```

Now about **`Service`** entity:

```
@Entity
class Service
int id
String name
//This is our foreign key from Category table
int categoryId //It can be Main/Sub category id from "Category" Table, how to detect it's Main/Sub? Check it from category table using "parentId".
```

> **Why this approach?**
>
> Because,
>
> 1 Service relies upon Category, so it doesn't matter for Service
>   whether Category is Main/Sub. All it knows is that it's Category for
>   itself.
>
> 2 Now for Category, *Why no separate tables for both of them?*
>   because, even though, it is Sub-category, we need to treat them like
>   Category(and it really is), So better treat it like Category and
>   differentiate both by one new parameter named **`parentId`** for it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. After doing some deep research I've decided to go with @Jeel Vankhede's so called Adjacency List Model - works fine and seems to fit my db struct better than Nested Set this time :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an old design called Nested Set. The advantages of this design is that it is relatively simple and you can create categories and subcategories to any depth. The queries are fast and can retrieve the data in a wide variety of ways: eg., show the subcategories of a certain category which are at level 4.

One disadvantage is that the queries are somewhat complex but are really intuitive once you get over the learning curve.

Another disadvantage is the DML is very expensive, so this is only useful where the data, once established, is *very* stable.

If that seems to fit your needs, I provide more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377125/3658753) along with a lot of sample code.