# SQL statement to get all the users

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table and I am confuse how can I generate sql statement on this on how can I get **ALL** the u_id,that under    p_id as there parent id.

here is the output I want if want only 5 as the p_id.

```
users       usernames       p_id
7           miller           5
8           jamie            5
9           honey            7
10          jack             7
```

**gather_table**

```
p_id        u_id

null         1
1            5
1            6
5            7
5            8
7            9
7            10
```

**user table**

```
user_id      user_name

1            millan
2            john
3            max
4            chris
5            jane
6            lester
7            miller
8            jamie
9            Honey
10           Jack
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried >=6 but it returns 9 and 10,but 6 is never been p_id in my gather table so it has no u_id's on my gather table.

I want to get all the u_id of my p_id which is belong to it(p_id). in my example 5 is p_id of 7 8 9 10, eventhough the p_id of 9 and 10 is 7 but the p_id of 7 is 5,so they are still under 5

Comment: Do you know about [joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))?

Answer (score 2):

You can use left join for this purpose

```
SELECT `g`.`p_id`, `u`.* FROM `gather_table` as `g` LEFT JOIN `user_table` as `u` ON `g`.`u_id` = `u`.`user_id` WHERE `g`.`p_id` >= 5
```

UPDATE :

You can check the answer of [Finding all parents in mysql table with single query (Recursive Query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query)

But if there is only one parent each u_id, then I would suggest you to use Nested Set Table structure, which is more elegant way to handle this type of problem. In this the table structure would be like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_table` (
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`),
  KEY `idx_left_right` (`lft`,`rgt`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can take reference from this [article](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_nested_sets). This is specific to Joomla, but probably will be helpful.

Comment: I have something to say, what if the >= 6 but 6 has no u_id in my gather_table

Comment: Then it should return empty results.

Comment: Okay. Yes, my mistake. It will return the record of 9, 10. Which is correct according to your scenario. What do you want in that case?

Comment: Do I need to change my user table ? the one that you posted ?

Comment: I was confuse on how to insert the level

Comment: You can take reference from this code http://hg.joomla.org/joomla-platform/src/247ba8d88526/libraries/joomla/database/tablenested.php

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.user_id ,t1.user_name,t2.p_id from user as t1 
inner join gather as t2 on t1.user_id = t2.u_id
where t2.p_id >= 5
```

Your desired output shows you want p_id >= 5. Try join query for this
Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for more

Comment: what if >=6 ? but 6 never been p_id in my gather_table it has no u_id,but i tried your solution it return  9 and 10

Comment: Yes it will return 9,10 if you tried with >= 6 because 7 is the only p_id which is >= 6.So what is wrong with that.?

Answer (score 1):

use join on your table:

```
SELECT gather_table.p_id, user_table.* FROM gather_table  LEFT JOIN user_table ON gather_table.u_id = user_table.user_id WHERE gather_table.p_id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
select g.u_id,g.p_id,u.user_name from gather_table g,user_table u where g.u_id=u.user_id and g.u_id>=7
```