# SQL query on hierarchical data

Tags: connect-by

I am new to sql - trying to learn. I have a specific use case and need help with the same.

I have 2 tables and i need to run a query to join those and get the data back.

**Table A**
Parent Item
Child Item
Relationship Type

**Table B**
Item Name
Item ID
Item Color

So, the data is in such a way, where items can have hierarchical relationship. For eg:

> Item A is a parent for Item B and Item C. 
>   Item B is a parent for Item D and Item E.
>   Item D is a parent for Item F and Item G.

I need a query where i want to provide a Child Item and get back all the Parents until its last level in the hierarchy. 
For eg: If i provide Item G as the input, the output should give me a list of Items D, B and A.

I don't know if CONNECT BY is something that i can use, but need help with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What SQL are you using? MySQL, SQL server, Postgres, etc.?

Comment: Actually - Postgresql

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do something like this directly in Postgres because I haven't used it (I use MySQL). This type of thing is usually done with a server-side scripting language like PHP in a loop that returns the parent of each child. This thread shows a way to do it in MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query-recursive-query but I don't know if there's a way to convert it to Postgres.