# Mysql(version 5.6) hierarchy query all parents when nodes have more than one parent

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

I've searched a lot to find my answer, the most related one is [Finding all parents in mysql table with single query (Recursive Query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query-recursive-query/12948271)

The answer is great, but I found that this solution is not working when one node has more than one parent. Table like this:

```
id, node_id, parent_id
 1,       1,         2
 2,       2,         3    <-----
 3,       2,         4    <-----
 4,       4,         5
 5,       5,         6
 6,       6,         7
```

Notice that the line 2 and line 3, the node which has `node_id=2` has more than one parent.

The answer mentioned above will only return parent id of `2, 3, 4` when `node_id=1`, which is not true. (Should be `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`)

Comment: MySQL 5.6 does not support recursive queries, so you cannot do this (safely) with a single select.  You can use a recursive stored procedure, change the data model (to include the complete path in each row), or upgrade to MySQL 8+.

Comment: *I've searched a lot to find my answer, the most related one is Finding all parents in mysql table with single query (Recursive Query)* This is fake solution, it requires `parent_id < id` strongly (or backward) for all records in addition to "only one parent" relation.