# How to list all children with their root parent in a hierarchy using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database table which has list of locations with there parent location id in hierarchical manner so i want to list all the locations with their **root parent location**

Following is the sample table

```
id     location_name  parent_id
1         a             0            
2         b             0
3         c             0
4         d             1
5         e             1
6         f             5
7         g             4
8         k             2
9         l             8
10        j             9
```

Following is the result i want

```
id     location_name  root_parent_name
1         a             a            
2         b             b
3         c             c
4         d             a
5         e             a
6         f             a
7         g             a
8         k             b
9         l             b
10        j             b
```

parent name is root parent location

Comment: You request is unclear! What is the relation between the `parent_name` and the `parent_id`?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui actually its root_parent_name. I have edited the question

Comment: @Shadow i have refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18894775) answer and made following query but no luck with the same            `query`select @location_id:=l.parent_id, l.location_name, ( 
select location_name from (select 
  @parent:=parent_id, location_name
from
  (select @parent:=@location_id) a
join 
  (select * from location_master where location_type_id != 1 order by id desc) b
where 
  @parent=id
order by @parent asc limit 1) c ) as root_parent from location_master l`query`

Comment: you cannot do that in single query in mysql, it lacks recursive queries, as your parent child tree can be of any size

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 SELECT t1.name as parent, t2.`name` as name FROM `test` t1 RIGHT JOIN `test` t2 ON t2.`p_id` = t1.id
```