# Mysql query not getting all parent ids

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch all the child ids (comma separeted) but my code just getting the two level heirachy, not more than that. I dont know whats issue? here is my code

```
 select concat (a.id,',',a.parent_id) as parents
  from table1 a 
 inner join  table1 b 
    on a.id = b.parent_id
 where b.id = 5
```

Here is my table structure:

```
    id | parent_id
    ---------------------
     1 |      6
     2 |      NULL
     3 |         1
     4 |         3
     5 |         4
     6 |      NULL
     7 |      NULL
```

output expected:

```
4,3,1,6
```

Comment: what do you expect by the way? can you tell us that?

Comment: How many levels do you have?

Comment: Should be general. dynamic leve

Comment: This question provide a solution with dynamic levels [Getting all parent rows in one SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441821/getting-all-parent-rows-in-one-sql-query)

Comment: The child ids would be 1, 3, 4, 5. Perhaps you want the parent_ids

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(@temp:=T.parent_id) as parents
FROM (SELECT * FROM testTable ORDER BY id DESC) T
 JOIN
 (SELECT @temp:=5)tmp
WHERE T.id=@temp;
```

> Refer : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9fb7c/11)